# Python - parsing Half-JSON Formatted Text

Tags: python, json, parsing, config, jsonparser

I've been mulling over a problem, but I can't seem to figure out the right path forward, so here goes.

I'm attempting to parse a Config file, however it's not written like a normal .conf file, and is almost in a Half-JSON format. Here's an example of how the data is written out:

```
{
  TEST {
    test1 = "test description"
    test2 = "test description 2"
    test inner {
      innertest = "(something && something)"
      innertest2 = """something else"""
    }
  TEST2 {
    test1 = "test description"
    test2 = "test description 2"
    test inner {
      innertest = "(something && something)"
      innertest2 = """something else"""
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's got the indentation and nesting of JSON, but without the double quotes/quotes needed to use the normal JSON parser.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to parse this into python? My actual end goal was just to parse specific field names (e.g. test1, test2) into a table using Pandas, but if there's a way you can think of that bypasses this, feel free to sugest that also.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like [ECON](https://ec-lang.org/econ/).

Comment: Where'd this config file come from?  Before you write your own parser, it'd be worth reading the docs for the associated tool to see if the format has a name and if there's a library for parsing it.  (It doesn't look familiar to me, but that doesn't mean there aren't a bunch of people/tools using it.)